# Please improve the appearance of the preview area when editing a post from a review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, edits

When editing a post while reviewing with the review guidance open, scrolling down to preview the post is kind of awkward. As soon as more than a few lines of the preview are visible, the entire edit area disappears at once, hiding the edit area behind the guidance. This makes the editing experience suboptimal:

[image]

Comment: Yup, that's poor UX...